# Draw a line through two points of an image python matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I have an image which I am loading into a 2D array using pyfits. I want to draw a line through two pixels on the image and save it with the new line added (not plot) . After this I want to draw a line perpendicular to the previous line with different colour.  What is the best way to achieve this using matplotlib ? I tried it with PIL. I wasn't able to do it. Please look at the code and suggest me a way to do this. I'm attaching the image also

```
def plotAxes(map, angle, x_centroid, y_centroid):
    hor = math.floor(x_centroid + 20*(math.cos(angle)))
    ver = math.floor(y_centroid - 20*(math.sin(angle)))
    hor1 = math.floor(x_centroid + 20*(math.cos(angle+90.0)))
    ver1 = math.floor(y_centroid - 20*(math.sin(angle+90.0)))
    map_height = len(map)
    map_width = len(map[0])
    point = [ver, hor]
    center = [y_centroid, x_centroid]
    Max = np.max(map)
    array = np.zeros((map_height, map_width), int)
    for i in range(0, map_height):
        for j in range(0, map_width):
            array[i][j] = (math.floor((float(map[i][j])/float(Max))*255))
    im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(array))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im) 
    draw.line((x_centroid,y_centroid, hor,ver  ), fill="red")
    draw.line((x_centroid,y_centroid, hor1,ver1  ), fill="red")
    im.show()
```

But the above code doesn't seem to print the lines perpendicularly. The angle looks 120 instead of 90.

[image]

Comment: This edit definitely improves the question; voting to reopen.

Comment: I made the necessary changes . sorry for not being clearer before :) . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry . I made a mistake passing the angle into Sin and cos in degrees. I passed in radians and it worked . Thankyou

```
angle = (angle * math.pi)/180
hor = math.floor(x_centroid + 20*(math.cos(angle)))
ver = math.floor(y_centroid - 20*(math.sin(angle)))
hor1 = math.floor(x_centroid + 20*(math.cos(angle+ (math.pi)/2)))
ver1 = math.floor(y_centroid - 20*(math.sin(angle+(math.pi)/2)))
```